# Org-mode font size changes with formatting

Tags: org-mode, font-lock, formatting

In Windows I've set my default font height to `120` with:

```el
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 120)
```

This seems to not take effect in `org-mode`, however, when specially formatting is applied. For example, when I use `//` or `**` to italicize or bold, the font size shrinks when the formatting is applied. What setting am I missing to have org-mode use the correct formatting with its specially formatted text. The rest of the text looks right. It's just the formatted stuff that is shrunk.

Example below. Note that after the "have," the text no longer aligns because the italicized *have* has shrunk:

[image]

Comment: Place your cursor on the offending text and type `M-x customize-face` or, if you just want to find out more about what is there at that particular position, type `C-u C-x =`

Comment: Some modes have their own face configuration, in some cases they use different font and font size. For me setting the default font explicitly in the (set-face-attribute) fixes this. Like so:  `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Lucida Grande Mono" :height 120 :slant 'normal :weight 'normal)`  Also if you use a theme, it might change the default behavior so you need to put the (set-face-attribute) after you load your theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `italic` face too.

```
(set-face-attribute 'italic nil :height 120)
```

And you might need to set `bold` face too.

Comment: Is there a way to change them all with one command, or does it need to be three separate commands, one for default, one for italic, and one for bold?

Comment: You can set :height for three faces to 120 with mapc or something else, but italic face's :slant must be set separate. Check out the help of function set-face-attribute.